# How to search for the text within an "a href" tag and click?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I've got a table with a bunch of links. The IDs are all unique but do not correspond to the actual text that is displayed so I'm having some trouble.

Ex.

```
<tr>
  <td><a id="011" href="/link">Project 1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a id="235" href="/link">Project 2</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a id="033" href="/link">Project 3</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a id="805" href="/link">Project 4</a></td>
</tr>
```

I only know the text within the ahref (ie. Project 1) and I want to search for it and click it. I haven't been able to figure this out and I've been playing around with find_element_by_xpath for a while.

I've been using

```
selectproject = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,projectname)]").click();
```

(projectname is a variable that changes every iteration)
I think it works to find the element since the script runs but it doesn't click. I think it's because I'm not actually searching for the ahref and just for the text?

Comment: Does the `href` href attributes contains `"/link"` in real or some real links?

Comment: @DebanjanB it's actual links that are confirmed to work. This is just an example.

Comment: Are the `ids` static or dynamic? Are those real `ids` or just for demo purpose? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB They're static and fake for this purpose. But it basically mirrors what I'm trying to do. The reason I can't just use find_element_by_id is because I need to find the link based on the "Project 1" text, rather than the ID.

Comment: Try putting the projectname between two single quotes: "//a[contains(.,'projectname')]"

Comment: Not super familiar with this but shouldn't your xpath string be `"//a[contains(.,"+projectname+")]"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

If you want to click the link with text `Project 1` you can use the following line of code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Project 1')]").click()
```

> or

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id="011"][contains(text(),'Project 1')]").click()
```

### Update:

As you mentioned the `Project 1` part is dynamic so you can try to construct a separate `function()` for clicking these links. Call the function with all the *projectnames* one by one as follows (the function is in **`Java`** consider to convert as per your required language binding):

```
public void clickProject(String projectName)
{
    browser.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='" + projectName + "']")).click();
}
```

Now you can call from your `main()` class as: `clickProject(Project1)`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: *projectname is a variable that changes every iteration)*

Comment: I was hoping to have "projectname" be a variable that I read in. So If I wanted to select Project 1, I could just set projectname = "Project 1", or "Project 2", etc. I tried it putting the actual project name, like your answer, and it works. It's the variable portion that is not working for me.

Comment: If the _projectname_ is variable you may try to read it from a excel and pass it as a argument within the `xpath`. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB that is exactly what I am trying to do, read it from an excel spreadsheet and use the contents of that cell to find the element. But that isn't working for me. Putting it in quotes isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to "click on the link Project 1", then you should use *that* as the locator. No need to mess around with XPath.

```
    browser.find_element_by_linkText("Project 1").click();
    // or the more flexible
    browser.find_element_by_partialLinkText("Project 1").click();
```

The `.find_element_by_partialLinkText()` locator strategy should account for any extra whitespace padding due to the extra `span` element.

**Note**: I write Java, so the above Python syntax may be off. But those methods must exist.